# How to map key and values in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mapping

I have the following response that I need to map into a useable format in typescript,

```
response => {

    Vehicles:
        BMW: Array(3)
            0: {ModelName: "M3", ModelUid: "14711"}
            1: {ModelName: "X3", ModelUid: "14712"}
            2: {ModelName: "Z4", ModelUid: "14713"}

        Aston Martin: Array(4)
            0: {ModelName: "DBS", ModelUid: "14742"}
            1: {ModelName: "DB9", ModelUid: "14743"}
            2: {ModelName: "V12 Vantage", ModelUid: "14744"}
            3: {ModelName: "Virage", ModelUid: "14745"}
```

I've done the below which works, but I think there must be a nicer way.

```
var vehicles = new Array();

var keys = Object.keys(response.Vehicles);

keys.forEach(key => {
    vehicles.push({ Manufacturer: key, Models: [] });
});

for (var i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++)
{
    var name = vehicles[i].Manufacturer;
    vehicles[i].Models = response.Vehicles[name];
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into using a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You *could* simplify your code to this:

```
var vehicles = new Array();

var keys = Object.keys(response.Vehicles);

keys.forEach(key => {
    vehicles.push({ Manufacturer: key, Models: response.Vehicles[name] });
});
```

No need to loop through `Vehicles` twice.

In general, however, you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for data transformation like this. Whether that's always "nicer" is a bit subjective, but this would work:

```
const vehicles = Object.keys(response.Vehicles).map((vehicleKey) => {
    return {
        Manufacturer: vehicleKey,
        Models: response.Vehicles[vehicleKey],
    }
});
```

As a rule of thumb, you should only need `Array.forEach` in JavaScript when you need a side effect, which is not your case; you only need data transformation.